# Search all variables for certain values

Tags: c++, variables, visual-studio-2013

I'm curious if visual studio has some feature to allow searching for all available variables inside my program for certain values?

Basically I would like to have something similar to cheat engine where I am able to search memory several times and filter out more and more other variables and finally get that which I'm interested about.

Maybe there is some separate plugin or some better approach to get same result.

Comment: What do you mean? Variable values may change during runtime.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think he's asking about doing this in the VS debugger.

Comment: @Barmar Setting _watch condiitons_ may be a solution, but the question is quite unclear at all.

Comment: watch conditions allows to execute breakpoint if some variable is equals to some value.

In my case I know only value, nothing more and i want to find all variables(int, long int,double etc) that contain that value. I dont know how to describe it more precise. Please google for Cheat Engine and how it works.